# Xcode Playground spaces taken away?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift-playground

Someone please help!! The fact that these upside down brackets are taking the space between my words are annoying.

It looks like this...

_var_five_=_5

Comment: Please provide more info, I can't understand your problem

Comment: _var_=_5 Everytime i press the spacebar this type of character "_" replaces the white space that is suppose to be there

Comment: "_" sorry this character

Comment: sorry just an upside down bracket shaped charater

Comment: I also don't know what you mean by "upside down bracked shaped character" but it sounds like somethings really messed up. Try restarting your Mac, restarting XCode, check that you've got an up to date version

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode, use the Editor menu and Hide Invisibles.